# Targeting API 17 Compile Issue

Tags: android

I need to build an application that specifically targets API 17, including the compileSDK version. I started a new project and change the min, target and compileSDK version to 17 and am getting a slew of problems"

[image]

Is there a way to get this to compile before starting the project?

Comment: SDK version 17 is android `4.2`, Most of those attributes that are throwing the errors don't exist until sdk version `21`. Targeting the latest version does not mean you cant support sdk 17

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to target API 17, however you need to set your `compileSdkVersion` in your `build.gradle` to the latest API level to let the code compile with your current dependencies.

For example your `build.gradle` can look like something like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
}
```

However, as mentioned by others, your app will not be able to be published in the Play Store since as of **1 August 2018**, developers needs to target at least API 26 for new apps.

Answer (score 0):

You should always be targeting the latest version of Android. You won't even be able to get your app on Google Play with a targetSdk lower than 26. Keep your minSdk at 17, and switch your target/compile to 27 (or 28, since Android 9.0 Pie was released this week).

Answer (score 0):

Google [Update](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk):

> Google Play will require that new apps target at least Android 8.0
>   (API level 26) from August 1, 2018, and that app updates target
>   Android 8.0 from November 1, 2018.

If you are planning to distribute your app using third-party distributors (such as HockeyApp) then you can use older version of Android Studio (less than 2.3) and older Gradle version.

Using latest Android Studio and Gradle requires updated version of SDKs, if not latest.

For Play Store release use latest version of SDKs and APIs.